# Integration and limit of a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, limits

> Calculate $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^{x} \! \frac{1}{2+\cos t}\,\mathrm{d}t}{x}$$

I tried to use L'Hopital but I obtained a function which has no limit (because $\cos$ doesn't have a limit to infinity). I also find the exact form of the integral, but I don't understand how to use this.

Comment: Try to show that the mean value of a periodic and bounded function is the mean value over a period.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, the limit expresses the *mean value* of $f(t)=\frac1{2+\cos t}$ over $\Bbb R^+$. Since $f$ is periodic and bounded, we only need to compute the mean over one period:
$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{2+\cos t}\,dt$$
The integral happens to work out to $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}$ – as can be worked out by, say, tangent half-angle substitution – so the mean value is $\frac1{\sqrt3}$.